# CSS / LESS to change background colour of selected options in multiselect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a twitter bootstrap styled multi select box, but I cannot find the correct css or less selector to overwrite the background colour for the selected options.

E.g. in image below, the selected option (Test 3), has a background colour of blue. How do I change this colour?

When Inspecting Element in Chrome, I cannot find any form of hint as to the css which is used to change the colour of the selected options.

[image: Trying to style background colour of selected element in multiselect]

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="1" size="7" id="requested_tests" name="requested_tests">
    <option value="1">Test 123</option>
    <option value="2">Test 212</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="4">Test 4</option>
    <option value="5">Test 5</option>
    <option value="6">A Test</option>
    <option value="7">Asdff</option>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to do this with CSS. There is a hacky way of (kinda) doing it (see http://jsfiddle.net/Etr4F/). You will need to use javascript anyway to harvest the options in the fake dropdown so you might as well use something like ddSlick (http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) or one of the many other jQuery dropdown plugins available out there.

Comment: Bummer!!! Oh well, it wasn't necessary, just a bit frustrating when you have a beautifully styled form, then have a background colour which looks out of place.

Comment: ddSlick, as the name suggests, is quite slick and easy to set up - it means you can keep your old `select` elements, and cover them over with an `input mask`. I advise you to use that.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your styles,

```css
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: red; /*you color here*/
    background-image: none;
}
```

Alternatively, alter the class within bootstrap-theme.css.